# How can I hide a field with Views if another field has a certain value?

Tags: 7, entities, views, panels

In my Drupal 7.8 website (with the Views and Panels modules installed), I'm trying to display a view pane in a panel. However, I only want to show certain fields in that pane if another field has a certain value.

Example: I display fields Foods, Healthy, and Unhealthy from a node using a custom view pane. But I only want to display fields Healthy and Unhealthy if field Foods (which is a multi-select field) contains the value "Cheetos"

Does anybody know how I can do this with a plugin or with views default functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution1:
You can add filter in view by selecting and restricting the value of "Foods" field since if foods has the selected option then only it will display the results.

Solution2:
Just add one more field with php custom field(use views customfield module) and exclude display of all other 3 fields. In this php field you can get all the previous field values in $data variable so you can print the result as you wish by validating using php.

Hope this can help you out!

Comment: Wow! Yep! That's great! The php custom field is exactly what I wanted -- and it helps solve several other problems. Thanks!